# How to read my file correctly?

Tags: bash, files, read

I have a question about how to read my file correctly in UNIX, I have the file given (attached as image) and this file has tabs between the variables, as you can see Blood is a variable and Whole Blood is another one. However, when I write in the terminal `gawk '{print $7}'file.txt | head` the result is the other attached image that you can see. I mean, the system is counting like this:

```
GTEX-1117F-0003-SM-58Q7G ($1)
B1 ($2)
Blood ($3)
Blood ($4)
Whole ($5)
0013756 ($6)
1188 ($7)
```

At this position should be Whole Blood and not 1188, so I need to know how could I solve this problem.
I need something like this:

Thanks in advance

[image: File given]
[image]
[image: file needed]

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. The images are unfortunately completely useless for us since we cannot take them and test any solutions we come up with.

Comment: Are you just looking for `gawk -F'\t' '{print $7}' file.txt`?

Comment: Thank you for answering, and yes the command worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable Input Field Separator defaults to all kinds of spaces. You want it to explicitly set it to a tab. The man page of awk says:

```
  -F sepstring
             Define the input field separator. This option shall be
             equivalent to:

                 -v FS=sepstring
```

And further down:

```
  FS        Input field  separator  regular expression; a <space> by default.
```

So, to set the FS to a tab:

```
$ awk -F'\t' '{print $7}' file.txt
```

Comment: thank your for your response. Now, I understood why I needed -F and ' \t'. I'm new in this, so I didn't know what to do.